# Syntax error in my method while using sort clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def index
  sort_init 'start_date', 'desc'
  sort_update %w(start_date created_at updated_at)

  @timesheet_pay_periods = TimesheetPayPeriod.all, :order => sort_clause
  @timesheet_pay_period = TimesheetPayPeriod.new

  render :layout => !request.xhr?
end
```

I have this method  in my timesheet controller. The issue is that I am not able to get the sort clause to work.
I get this error:

> SyntaxError (/home/archana/ruby-test/redmine/plugins/arc_timesheets/app/controllers/timesheet_pay_periods_controller.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end
>   ...mesheetPayPeriod.all, :order => sort_clause

but not able to make out where the issue is? can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error getting the all records. You should change

```
@timesheet_pay_periods = TimesheetPayPeriod.all, :order => sort_clause
```

to this

```
# you have an extra comma
# it's better to use .order
@timesheet_pay_periods = TimesheetPayPeriod.order sort_clause
```